# Where does pam get credential information?

Tags: authentication, pam

I am learning how to write a application program which use pam to do authentication. I checked the Linux documents and some example codes, now I have a basic understanding about the pam APIs and pam configuration in /etc/pam.d/.

But I have a question is where pam get the credential information to do authentication. E.g.: If the application send the pam request with username "abc" and password "XXXXX".

How does pam check the credential information to determine whether authenticate or not? If "abc" is not a valid user for my application, but I want to add it as a valid user, how should I do to make pam authenticatin succeed ?

Comment: Seems like a question more suited for Ubuntu Forum.:-) Hoping someone will answer soon.

Comment: Start bt reading `man pam_authenticate`, also read the `man` pages for `pam_start(3), pam_setcred(3), pam_chauthtok(3), pam_strerror(3), pam(7)`.

Comment: @waltinator, thank you for suggestions. I read man pages for pam_setcred and pam_chauthtok. But I still didn't get my answers.

Comment: for "int pam_setcred(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags)",  the man page described : The pam_setcred function is used to establish, maintain and delete the credentials of a user. It should be called to set the credentials after a user has been authenticated and before a session is opened for the user.
So it will be called after the user be authenticated. I don't think I can use it to add a valid user.

Comment: for "int pam_chauthtok(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags)". the man page described : 
The pam_chauthtok function is used to change the authentication token for a given user (as indicated by the state associated with the handle pamh).
It seems this function can't be used to add a user either.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear which confused you. Let me simplify my question to focus on how to add a user.

If "abc" is not a valid user for my application, but I want to add it as a valid user, how should I do to make pam authenticatin succeed ? What function I can use to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can add a user to `pam` from within `pam`. **P**luggable **A**uthentication **M**odules.

Comment: That is ok. But where do Pluggable Authentication Modules get the information to determine whether this user can be authenticated or not ?